# generate and execute processing graphs in networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx, dataflow

I have a number of 'processes' each implemented as a class (implementing an interface - `process`) and a number of 'datasets', again represented by a class - `dataset`.

A directed acyclic graph of datasets and their dependecies can be created..It may look something like:

```
            root
           /   \
  dataset1a     dataset1b
     |              |
  dataset2      dataset2b
   /   |  \        /     \
dset3a | dset3b  dset4a dset4b
   \   |        /
    \  |       /
     \ |      /
     dataset3a4a
```

To get to each dataset, a process (represented by the `process` class) must be applied. Currently I am creating a `DiGraph` with network x where each dataset object is a node and the process to get to `X` node is an attribute on the node pointing to the `process` object. `ROOT` is just a dummy node to provide a starting node.

Is this a good way of representing the graph with networkx?
Given that `dataset1a` and `dataset1b` exist and their decendants must be created (where each previous dataset is an input to the `process` class)...what is a good way of traversing the graph such that:

- a node is not visited until all its' dependents have been visited (and the datasets therefore created)
- The dependent 'node' can be found...e.g. if I am at the `dataset3a4a` node, I must be able to discover all the 'inputs' to create that dataset - `dset3a`, `dset4a` and `dataset2`.

Answer (score 0):

Python provides some introspection tools which you could use instead of networkx. 
The `__subclasses__` method returns a list of the direct subclasess of the given class:

```
In [36]: Root.__subclasses__()
Out[38]: [__main__.DataSet1a, __main__.DataSet1b]
In [61]: DataSet2.__subclasses__()
Out[61]: [__main__.DSet3a, __main__.DSet3b, __main__.DataSet3a4a]
In [62]: DataSet3a4a.__subclasses__()
Out[62]: []
```

The `__bases__` attribute returns the bases (direct parent classes) of the class:

```
In [63]: DataSet3a4a.__bases__
Out[63]: (__main__.DSet3a, __main__.DataSet2, __main__.DSet4a)
```

The `__bases__` attribute provides the answer to your second question regarding
how to find the inputs to create a dataset.

To answer the first question, you can use `__subclasses__` and `__bases__` to
build your own traversal function:

```
import collections
class Root(object): pass
class DataSet1a(Root): pass
class DataSet1b(Root): pass
class DataSet2(DataSet1a): pass
class DataSet2b(DataSet1b): pass
class DSet3a(DataSet2): pass
class DSet3b(DataSet2): pass
class DSet4a(DataSet2b): pass
class DSet4b(DataSet2b): pass
class DataSet3a4a(DSet3a, DataSet2, DSet4a): pass

def visit(cls):
    seen = set([cls])
    queue = collections.deque(cls.__subclasses__())
    while queue:
        subcls = queue.popleft()
        if subcls in seen: continue
        # check that all its bases have been seen
        for base in subcls.__bases__:
            if base not in seen:
                # if a base has not been seen, push subcls to the back of the queue
                queue.append(subcls)
                break
        else:
            # all the bases of subcls have already been seen
            seen.add(subcls)
            yield subcls
        # add all the subclasses of subcls to the queue
        queue.extend(subcls.__subclasses__())

for cls in visit(Root):
    print(cls.__name__)
```

yields

```
DataSet1a
DataSet1b
DataSet2
DataSet2b
DSet3a
DSet3b
DSet4a
DSet4b
DataSet3a4a
```